# Retrieving row data from a JTable using rowindex

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I retrieve row data from a `JTable` using its rowindex?

Comment: how about reading the api doc and a basic tutorial like f.i. the one referenced in the Swing tag wiki? Both come with example code that you might adapt to your needs.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened because the question _is_ a real and valid question. I've navigated to this question because I'm working on a GUI in Java and I'm not completely familiar with JTables and their intricacies. Although worded in a less than ideal way, this is a clear question. I've edited the question to add clarity. It can clearly be understood that this question is asking for a way to retrieve the data from a given row in a JTable if you know its rowindex. This is not ambiguous or vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical. This question should be reconsidered.

Comment: Agree.  Nominated to reopen.

Answer (score 11):

I think this can be done in a few less lines than @user489041's answer.  ;-)

Try this sample code:

```
int selectedRowIndex = jTable.getSelectedRow();
int selectedColumnIndex = jTable.getSelectedColumn();
Object selectedObject = (Object) jTable.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColumnIndex);
```

Replace "Object" with whatever you stored in the table, such as "String".

If you have set your JTable so that the user can only select an entire row, then replace "selectedColumnIndex" with the index of the column from which you want to retrieve the content.

Answer (score 3):

In Swing every UI Component has a corresponding model which 'manages' the data. Most of the time you can get the model by calling `getModel()` on the component. For `JTable` the model is the class [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html). There you can use the methods `getRowCount()`, `getValueAt(x,y)` and `getColumnCount()` to access the data of the table.

Answer (score 2):

```
 
 

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;

/**
 * Basic JTable with some convenience methods.
 * @author dvargo
 */
public class ConvenienceTable extends JTable
{

    /**
     * The pop up menu for the table
     */
    private JPopupMenu Pmenu = new JPopupMenu();

    /**
     * Holds the currently being/last row clicked in the table.
     */
    private int rowClicked = -1;

    /**
     * Holds the currently being/last column clicked in the table.
     */
    private int colClicked = -1;

    /**
     * If the table is editable or not
     */
    private boolean isEditable = true;

    /**
     * Default construct that uses the default table model
     */
    public ConvenienceTable()
    {
        super();
        addPopUpMenu();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that lets you set the table model to use
     * @param model The table model you would like to use
     */
    public ConvenienceTable(AbstractTableModel model)
    {
        super(model);
        addPopUpMenu();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the contents of of a cell as a string
     * @param row The row of the cell
     * @param col The col of the cell
     * @return The string representation of a cell
     */
    public String getValueforCell(int row, int col)
    {
        return (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, col).toString();
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a single row with all cells empty into the table
     */
    public void insertRow()
    {
        //get the model the table is using
        TableModel temp = getModel();
        //cast it so we can do something useful with it
        DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) temp;
        tm.addRow(new Object[]{});
        resizeAndRepaint();
    }

    /**
     * Inserts multiple rows with each cell empty into the table
     * @param numberOfRowsToAdd The number of rows to add to the table
     */
    public void insertRow(int numberOfRowsToAdd)
    {
        //get the model the table is using
        TableModel temp = getModel();
        //cast it so we can do something useful with it
        DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRowsToAdd; i++)
        {
            tm.addRow(new Object[]{});
        }
    }
        /**
     * Insets a row with the given data as the rows contents
     * @param data The data to input into the row
     */
    public void insertRow(String[] data)
    {
        insertRow();
        int row = getRowCount() - 1;
        int colCounter = 0;
        for(String currData : data)
        {
            setValueAt(currData,row,colCounter);
            colCounter++;
            if(colCounter  &lgt = getColumnCount())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Inserts a column at the end of the columns.
     * @param colName The name for this column
     */
    public void insertColumn(String colName)
    {
        //get the model the table is using
        TableModel temp = getModel();
        //cast it so we can do something useful with it
        DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) temp;
        tm.addColumn(colName, new Object[]
                {
                });
        getTableHeader().resizeAndRepaint();
        resizeAndRepaint();
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a multiple columns into the table
     * @param numberOfColumns The number of columns to add to the table
     */
    public void insertColumn(int numberOfColumns)
    {
        //get the model the table is using
        TableModel temp = getModel();
        //cast it so we can do something useful with it
        DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            tm.addColumn(new Integer(i).toString(), new Object[]
                    {
                    });
            getTableHeader().resizeAndRepaint();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a row from the table at a given index
     * @param rowIndex The row index to delete. Row index 0 is below the column
     * headers
     */
    public void deleteRow(int rowIndex)
    {
        if (rowIndex < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        //get the model the table is using
        TableModel temp = getModel();
        //cast it so we can do something useful with it
        DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) temp;
        tm.removeRow(rowIndex);
        getTableHeader().resizeAndRepaint();
    }

    /**
     * Delete a column from the table
     * @param colIndex The index of the column to delete
     */
    public void deleteColumn(int colIndex)
    {
        if (colIndex < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        removeColumn(getColumnModel().getColumn(colIndex));
        getTableHeader().resizeAndRepaint();
    }

    /**
     * Changes the name of a column
     * @param colIndex The index of the column to change name
     * @param newName The name of the column
     */
    public void setColumnName(int colIndex, String newName)
    {
        getColumnModel().getColumn(colIndex).setHeaderValue(newName);
        getTableHeader().resizeAndRepaint();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the columns of the table
     */
    public void setColumnNames(String[] names)
    {
        setNumberOfCols(names.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            setColumnName(i, names[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the number of row in the table to a certain value. The rows are added
     * to the end of the table
     * @param numberOfRows The number of rows that should be in the table
     *
     */
    public void setNumberOfRows(int numberOfRows)
    {
        if (numberOfRows == getRowCount() || numberOfRows < 0) //user requested the same number of rows
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (numberOfRows  &lgt  getRowCount()) //user requested more rows
        {
            int numberOfRowsToAdd = Math.abs(getRowCount() - numberOfRows);
            insertRow(numberOfRowsToAdd);
        }
        else if (numberOfRows < getRowCount()) //user request les rows
        {
            int numberOfRowsToDelete = Math.abs(getRowCount() - numberOfRows);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRowsToDelete; i++)
            {
                deleteRow(getRowCount() - 1);
            }
        }
        resizeAndRepaint();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the number of cols for the table. The columns are added and deleted
     * at the end of the table
     * @param numberOfCols
     */
    public void setNumberOfCols(int numberOfCols)
    {
        //user requested the same number of rows
        if (numberOfCols == getColumnCount() || numberOfCols < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (numberOfCols  &lgt  getColumnCount()) //user requested more rows
        {
            int numberOfColsToAdd = Math.abs(getColumnCount() - numberOfCols);
            insertColumn(numberOfColsToAdd);
        }
        else if (numberOfCols  getColumnCount()) //user request les rows
        {
            int numberOfColsToDelete = Math.abs(getColumnCount() - numberOfCols);
            for (int i = 0; i  <  numberOfColsToDelete; i++)
            {
                deleteColumn(getColumnCount() - 1);
            }
        }
        resizeAndRepaint();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the string name value of the column
     * @param colIndex The index of the column whose name you want
     * @return The name of the column
     */
    public String getColumnName(int colIndex)
    {
        return (String) getColumnModel().getColumn(colIndex).getHeaderValue();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array holding all the column names
     * @return The column names
     */
    public String[] getColumnNames()
    {
        String[] colNames = new String[getColumnCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i  <  getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            colNames[i] = getColumnName(i);
        }
        return colNames;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the index in the table for a column with the given name
     * @param colName The name of the column
     * @return The index of the column in the table or -1 if it is not found
     */
    public int getColumnIndex(String colName)
    {
        String [] names = getColumnNames();
        int retVal = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i <  names.length; i++)
        {
            if(names[i].equals(colName))
            {
                retVal = i;
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    /**
     * Allows the user to paste multiple lines and columns into the table
     * @param row The row where the paste is to start from
     * @param col The column where the paste is to start from
     */
    public void paste(int row, int col)
    {
        //used to determine what info goes in which coloumn of the table
        String newLineDelim = "\n";
        //used to determine what info goes in what cell in a row
        String nextElementDelim = "\t";

        String pasteString = ClipboardUtility.getClipboardContents(); //get this info on the clipboard


        //see if we can handle parsing this string
        if (pasteString.contains(newLineDelim) == false || pasteString.contains(nextElementDelim) == false)
        {
            //paste it all into the first cell if we done recognize it
            setValueAt(pasteString, row, col);
        }

        //parse the columns first
        String[] pasteSplitString = pasteString.split(newLineDelim);

        String[] temp = null;
        String[][] finalInfo = new String[pasteSplitString.length][getColumnCount()];

        //now parse the columns into the individual cells
        for (int i = 0; i  <  pasteSplitString.length; i++)
        {
            temp = pasteSplitString[i].split(nextElementDelim);
            finalInfo[i] = temp;
        }

        //put this info in the table
        for (int i = 0; i  <  finalInfo.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j  <  finalInfo[i].length; j++)
            {
                //its in a try catch incase the indexes do not match up, allows us to do a partial paste
                try
                {
                    //see if you need to add a row to the table
                    if (i + row  &lgt  getRowCount() - 1)
                    {
                        insertRow();
                    }
                    getModel().setValueAt(finalInfo[i][j], i + row, j + col);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println("Could not paste");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Copies the text in the selected cells in the table to the clipboard
     */
    public void copy()
    {
        //were going to use the \t for next column and \n for next row format
        String newCol = "\t";
        String newRow = "\n";

        //index to start coping from
        int rowStart = getSelectedRow();
        int colStart = getSelectedColumn();

        //index to stop copying from
        int colEnd = colStart + getSelectedColumnCount();
        int rowEnd = rowStart + getSelectedRowCount();

        //will hold the string of data were copying
        StringBuilder copyString = new StringBuilder();

        //copy it cell by cell
        for (int row = rowStart; row  <  rowEnd; row++)
        {
            if (row != rowStart)
            {
                copyString.append(newRow);
            }
            for (int col = colStart; col  <  colEnd; col++)
            {
                String currCellVal = (String) (getValueAt(row, col));
                //so you dont get "null" copied to the clipboard
                if (currCellVal == null)
                {
                    currCellVal = "";
                }
                copyString.append(currCellVal);
                if (col + 1  <  colEnd)
                {
                    copyString.append(newCol);
                }
            }
        }

        //post the string to the clipboard
        ClipboardUtility.setClipboardContents(copyString.toString());

    }

    /**
     * Returns the table as a array of strings with the data separated by a delimiter.
     * Each string in the array represents a row in the table.
     * @param delim The delimiter to separate the columns by
     * @return The data in the table
     */
    public String[] getTableData(String delim)
    {
        String[] data = new String[getRowCount()];

        int colCount = getColumnCount();
        int rowCount = getRowCount();

        //get the row data
        StringBuffer currRow = new StringBuffer();
        for (int row = 0; row  <  rowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col  <  colCount; col++)
            {
                currRow.append(getValueAt(row, col));
                currRow.append(delim);
            }
            data[row] = currRow.toString();
            currRow = new StringBuffer();
        }
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data in the table as a 2d string array [row][col]
     * @return The data in the table
     */
    public String[][] getTableData()
    {
        String[][] data = new String[this.getRowCount()][this.getColumnCount()];
        for (int r = 0; r  <  getRowCount(); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c  <  getColumnCount(); c++)
            {
                data[r][c] = getValueforCell(r, c);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Return a row from the table as a array of strings
     * @param rowIndex The index of the row you would like
     * @return Returns the row from the table as an array of strings or null if
     * the index is invalid
     */
    public String[] getRowData(int rowIndex)
    {
        //test the index
        if (rowIndex  &lgt  getRowCount() || rowIndex  <  0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        ArrayList < String &lgt  data = new ArrayList < String &lgt ();
        for (int c = 0; c  <  getColumnCount(); c++)
        {
            data.add((String) getValueforCell(rowIndex, c));
        }
        String[] retVal = new String[data.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i  <  retVal.length; i++)
        {
            retVal[i] = data.get(i);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data for a row as a hash map with the column being the key
     * and the cell being the value
     * @param rowIndex The row to get the data for
     * @return A map represneting the row
     */
    public Map < String,String &lgt  getRowDataAsMap(int rowIndex)
    {
        Map < String,String &lgt  retVal = new HashMap < String, String &lgt ();
        String [] rowData = getRowData(rowIndex);
        String [] colData = getColumnNames();
        for(int i = 0; i  <  colData.length; i++)
        {
            retVal.put(colData[i],rowData[i]);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the data in the table
     * @param data String array of delimited data for the table
     * @param delim The delimeter
     */
    public void setData(String[] data, String delim)
    {
        setNumberOfCols(parseTableData(data[0], delim).length);
        setNumberOfRows(data.length);
        String[] currRow;
        for (int r = 0; r  <  data.length; r++)
        {
            currRow = parseTableData(data[r], delim);
            for (int c = 0; c  <  currRow.length; c++)
            {
                setValueAt(currRow[c], r, c);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the values in the table
     * @param data
     */
    public void setData(String[][] data)
    {
        setNumberOfRows(data.length);
        setNumberOfCols(data[0].length);
        for (int r = 0; r  <  data.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c  <  data[r].length; c++)
            {
                setValueAt(data[r][c], r, c);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the data for a table starting at a given location in the table
     * @param data The delimited data to add to the table
     * @param delim The delimiter for the data
     * @param row The row where to start adding the data
     * @param col The col where to start adding the table
     */
    public void setData(String[] data, String delim, int row, int col)
    {
        setNumberOfCols(col + parseTableData(data[0], delim).length);
        setNumberOfRows(row + data.length);
        String[] currRow;
        for (int r = row; r  <  data.length; r++)
        {
            currRow = parseTableData(data[r], delim);
            for (int c = col; c  <  currRow.length; c++)
            {
                setValueAt(currRow[c], r, c);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes all the rows in the table
     */
    public void clearTable()
    {
        DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) getModel();
        dm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a menu item to the pop up menu with an action listener.
     * @param newItem The menu item to add
     * @param actionListener The actionlistener to add to this menu item
     */
    public void addPopUpMenuItem(JMenuItem newItem, ActionListener actionListener)
    {
        newItem.addActionListener(actionListener);
        Pmenu.add(newItem);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a menu item to the pop up menu. Not this can be as simple Jseparator
     * or a menu item with a actionlistener already attached.
     * @param newItem The menu item to add
     */
    public void addPopUpMenuItem(JMenuItem newItem)
    {
        Pmenu.add(newItem);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a separator to the JMenu
     */
    public void addPopUpMenuSeperator()
    {
        Pmenu.add(new JSeparator());
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current row being clicked
     * @return The current row being clicked
     */
    public int getRowClicked()
    {
        return rowClicked;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current column being clicked
     * @return The current column being clicked
     */
    public int getColClicked()
    {
        return colClicked;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the pop up menu and additional functionality to the table. The key
     * thing here is that this function adds the action listeners that determine
     * what row and what column is being clicked in the table.
     */
    private void addPopUpMenu()
    {
        //sets the popup menu so it will show
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                rowClicked = rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                colClicked = columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if (e.isPopupTrigger())
                {
                    Pmenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                rowClicked = rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                colClicked = columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Parses out the table data from a string (usually xml) using the passed in
     * delimiter. This is pretty much just like the sting classes split method
     * @param data The data to parse
     * @param delim The delimiter to use
     * @return An array of the tokens parsed out of the data string
     */
    public String[] parseTableData(String data, String delim)
    {
        ArrayList < String &lgt  tempArrayHolder = new ArrayList < String &lgt ();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, delim);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            tempArrayHolder.add(st.nextToken());
        }
        String[] retValArray = new String[tempArrayHolder.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i  <  tempArrayHolder.size(); i++)
        {
            retValArray[i] = tempArrayHolder.get(i);
        }
        return retValArray;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the table is editable or not. Note that this is for the whole
     * table and not individual cells.
     * @param isEditable True if the table is editable, false if the table is not
     * editable
     */
    public void setEditable(boolean isEditable)
    {
        this.isEditable = isEditable;
    }


    /**
     * Overridden to allow the hole table to be set to non editable or editable.
     * Depends on the value of isEditable
     * @param row The for the cell to see if it is editable
     * @param col The col for the cell to see if it is editable
     * @return True if the cell is editable false otherwise
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
    {
        if (isEditable == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return super.isCellEditable(row, col);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the indexes of the selected rows in the table
     * Overridden due to the inconsistent behavior of the default
     * @return A list of the selected rows
     */
    @Override
    public int[] getSelectedRows()
    {
        List < Integer &lgt  temp = new ArrayList < Integer &lgt ();
        for(int i = 0; i  <  getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            if(isRowSelected(i))
            {
                temp.add(i);
            }
        }
        int [] retVal = new int[temp.size()];
        for(int i =0; i  <  temp.size(); i++)
        {
            retVal[i] = temp.get(i);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

}
```